# Backup Windows on a running system

Tags: windows-7, windows, backup

The usual way to backup Windows is to clone the partition.
There are several problems with this method:

- It requires downtime.
- You have to do it manually.
- You cannot do incremental/differential backups (or not as easily).

Windows Backup backs up your computer while it's running, however there are several issues with Windows Backup so I don't use it. Does it just copy all the files into an archive? Can I restore Windows just by copying all the files on the drive? Why can't other programs back up a live Windows system like Windows Backup?

Comment: Windows backup only backs up your user files most people have needs beyond that

Comment: I'd just say when you are in dire need to recover a system, the system is not running then and it is done mostly manually, and more downtime will exists if that is not done easily and in one move. Taking a few moments out to lock down the system onto an external drive , when outside of the system, can save hours of grief with some backup that has system dependencies.  A full image clone of the system done outside of the system, can recover everything as easily as it was created to begin with.  What is lossed for the last week, usually could be file backed up.

Comment: `The usual way to backup Windows is to clone the partition` - Who says? `•It requires downtime` `•You have to do it manually` `•You cannot do incremental/differential backups (or not as easily)` - All three of those points are incorrect.

Comment: `Windows Backup backs up your computer while it's running, however there are several issues with Windows Backup so I don't use it.` - Really? What issues? Can you elaborate?

Comment: @joeqwerty Backup recommendations from various sites. The reason being to back up files that are in use and to have the system in a consistent state. Rebooting into a live CD to clone the partition is done manually, although it should be possible to automate it. Differential backups don't work as well because if some data moved, the backup program needs to be smart and see if any blocks moved to a different part of the partition. If the partition is encrypted that won't work either. If Windows could be backed up with a simple file-copy, then you could use a file-based backup with shadow copy.

Comment: @joeqwerty The system image included my D drive (3TB) which means it was too big to fit onto anything else and would take several hours. Also I couldn't specify which folder to put the backup in, only the drive. When my disk became full, the backup failed and it didn't delete old backups (maybe this is a good thing). This person had some other issues: http://www.virtualdub.org/blog/pivot/entry.php?id=376

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acronis True Image can back up the hard drive in the same manner.  The technology underlying this is volume shadow copy.  A copy of the original is made so it can lock it against writing so it can be backed up successfully.

The windows registry is locked and can not be replaced while windows is active.

There are many files which are locked/protected that you can not simply overwrite.

If you setup virtualization, say a vmware esxi server it can create real time snapshots of the whole image if vmware tools are installed.

Answer (score 1):

Back up windows to another disk to a VHD file using **Disk2VHD**. It uses volume shadow copy so you can do it while the system is running. You can then later mount the VHD file if need to recover files. Best of all, this solution is free.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-sg/sysinternals/ee656415.aspx